# Previous Fields getting emptied when adding new fields in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button on its click I am adding some input fields dynamically but when I add some values in one set of fields and add more fields the values of previous fields gets reset.

I am using ngfor for creating dynamic fields on button click

HTML is as follows

```html
  <div class="headerinput-field">

                        <mat-label>Headers </mat-label>
                        <br>
                        <a class="add-header" (click)="addHeader(header)">
                            <i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
                        </a>

                        <div>
                            <div *ngFor="let header of header;let i=index;">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="mockinput-field">
                                        <div>
                                            <mat-label> Key{{i}}</mat-label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mockableformInner methodinput-field">
                                                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter the key" name="test{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="header.headerkey" class="form-control" formControlName="header"
                                                    required />
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mockinput-field">
                                        <div>
                                            <mat-label class="label">Value</mat-label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mockableformInner methodinput-field">
                                                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Enter the value" name="test2{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="header.headervalue" class="form-control" formControlName="header"
                                                    required />
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                            <a (click)="removeHeader(i)" class="add-params">
                                                <i class="material-icons">cancel</i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
```

and my click functionality is as follows

```js
 addHeader() {
    
    this.header.push({headerkey: this.headerkey, headervalue:this.headervalue} );
    console.log(this.headerkey);
  }
```

Is there anyway to keep the previous fields value. I have tried giving unique name with indes but it doesnt work.

Comment: try to push empty value

Comment: @Chellappan Nope it is still resetting

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: Looks like you are pushing on same key every time. That's overriding the previous value .

Comment: @eduPeeth how do I push the different values then can i give some sort of index

Comment: You have < div *ngFor="let header of header;let i=index;" > don't use the same name for the array and for the variable. use some like < div *ngFor="let header of **headers**;let i=index;" >

Comment: Can you share your code on stackblitz as asked ?

Comment: @eduPeeth  heres the stackblitz. if you click on add_circle two fields will spawn, you add values in it and then again click on add_circle the values will reset:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6duxdb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Chellappan https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6duxdb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts heres the stackblitz. You can click on add_circle to add fields but the value will disappear after you click on add_circle again

Comment: why are you mixing template driven and reactive approach

Comment: i have remove the reactive approach its working check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ippmug

Comment: @Chellappan Thank you. It works!

Comment: you are welcome!!